# Custom-made spellchecker with Wiktionary

Tags: python, performance, beginner, python-3.x

I have been coding on Python for two weeks.

All I want the code to do is this:

- Check if each word in sentence has an English category Wiktionary article
- Ignore all words inside quotations and proper-nouns
- If the word doesn't have an English category Wiktionary article, add it to a list of misspellings
- For each misspelling, replace the misspelling with an auto-corrected version (if it doesn't auto-correct, blame the user for messing up so badly and leave it alone)

This is only one part of three in the python file that I want to use to correct the grammar of sentences (I plan to do punctuation-check next then grammar-check, the hardest one, last)

This is my current code:

```
import requests
from autocorrect import Speller
original_input = input("Input: ")
#Spelling
misspellings = []
quotation_parameters = []
quotation_indices = []
spelling_input = original_input
spelling_output = original_input
for i in "?.!,":
    spelling_input = spelling_input.replace(i, "")
words = spelling_input.split()
for index, i in enumerate(words):
    website1 = requests.get('https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/' + i)
    website2 = requests.get('https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/' + i.casefold())
    if (website1.status_code == 200 or website2.status_code == 200) and ("<span class=\"mw-headline\" id=\"English\">English</span>" in website1.text or "<span class=\"mw-headline\" id=\"English\">English</span>" in website2.text):
        print("\"" + i + "\"" + " is spelled right! :D")
    else:
        if (i[0] == '\'' or i[-1] == '\'') or (i[0] == '\"' or i[-1] == '\"'):
            quotation_parameters.append(index)
            for indexx, item in enumerate(quotation_parameters):
                if indexx % 2 == 0:
                    try:
                        quotation_indices.append(list(range(item, quotation_parameters[indexx + 1])))
                    except IndexError:
                        pass
        try:
            for j in quotation_indices:
                for k in j:
                    if words[k] in misspellings:
                        misspellings.remove(words[k])
        except IndexError:
            pass
        else:
            print("\"" + i + "\"" + " is spelled wrong... :(")
            misspellings.append(i)
    for word in misspellings:
        try:
            if (i[0] == '\'' or i[-1] == '\'') or (i[0] == '\"' or i[-1] == '\"'):
                misspellings.remove(i)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        spell = Speller(lang='en')
        if (word == spell(word) or word[0].isupper() == True):
            pass
        else:
            words = [spell(word) if x == word else x for x in words]
            spelling_output = spelling_output.replace(word, spell(word))
print(misspellings)
print(words)
print(spelling_output)
```

The code works, I guess (to an accuracy limited by the spellchecker module's library of words) - hence this wasn't posted on StackOverflow - but the problem is that it is really slow (around 20-60 seconds for new average-length sentence) and on top of that it looks really unneat and "*unpythonic*", I'm sure there is plenty of unnecessary try-excepts in there - this is the result of two days of trial and error - finding this and that on StackOverflow to debug the code. How can I improve the code's appearance and make the code's performance resemble closer to that of an average spell-checker like Grammarly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I would say you're quite ambitious with your choice of project. This isn't necessarily a bad thing and you can learn a lot along the way, but spelling and grammar checking of English beyond the simple sentences may not be easy. Consider the following weird, but valid sentence

> 'Tis naïve for Guinea-Bissau to serve hors d'oeuvre at the France-Côte d'Ivoire all-american BBQ; the grocers' response was unfavourable.

We have valid words in here, archaic words, ones that start end and with apostrophes, words which require particular capitalisation to be found, words with special characters, hypenated words, words which are only valid as multiple words, abbreviations, etc.

Regardless, it's an interesting project idea and I wish you the best of luck. Particularly with English grammar.

### Format

First off, you have no comments in your code, this makes it quite difficult to work out what this is doing. I'm not sure what `quotation_parameters` is supposed to do.

Also, you have no white-space in your code making it harder to visually parse.

Your variable names are also sometimes not helpful why `i`, not `word`, why `indexx`?

You also seem to have taken the odd choice of deliberately forcing yourself to escape quotes. In Python `"` and `'` are semantically identical, you can either be consistent throughout, or make the choice which makes your work easier. Instead of `"\""` we can use `'"'`; instead of `'\''` we can use `"'"`, if we're using them frequently enough we can do:

```
SINGLE_QUOTE = "'"
DOUBLE_QUOTE = '"'
```

And use constants to make it more obvious and readable.

In Python, we don't need parentheses around `if` statements and checking `if True` is a default operation (as well as numerous others such as is zero, is empty, etc.). Also, we tend to test against the value we want to check rather than `pass .. else`, so:

```
if (word == spell(word) or word[0].isupper() == True):
    pass
else:
    words = [spell(word) if x == word else x for x in words]
    spelling_output = spelling_output.replace(word, spell(word))
```

becomes

```
if word != spell(word) and not word[0].isupper():  ## Could also do `and word[0].islower()`
    words = [spell(word) if x == word else x for x in words]
    spelling_output = spelling_output.replace(word, spell(word))
```

### Probable logic errors

```
        if (i[0] == '\'' or i[-1] == '\'') or (i[0] == '\"' or i[-1] == '\"'):
```

This just checks if the first or last letters are `"` or `'`, i.e. `"the"`, `'tis`, `'so"`, `a"`, `Julius'` are all caught. The inner checks probably want to be `and` not `or`.

More helpfully, since we use this multiple times, we could also make this a function:

```
def isquoted(inp: str) -> bool:
    """Checks if a string is quoted

    :param inp: String to be checked
    :returns: true if quoted, else false

    """
    return ((inp.startswith("'") and inp.endswith("'")) or
            (inp.startswith('"') and inp.endswith('"')))
```

Also in this block

```
if (i[0] == '\'' or i[-1] == '\'') or (i[0] == '\"' or i[-1] == '\"'):
    [...]
try:
    [...]
except IndexError:
    [...]
else:  # <-- This else is attached to the `try` not the `if`, which probably isn't what you want
    [...]
```

### Efficiency

Every word of your sentence you are looping through every misspelling multiple times and removing duplicates. This function is built into Python in the `set` object. A `set` is a type which stores one copy of each of the elements. This means that instead of having to check `if word in misspellings` and filter duplicates, we just do:

```
misspellings = set()

misspellings.add(word)
```

It will never store duplicate copies.

### Standard Libraries

You are attempting to strip out the punctuation from your string, but there is much more possible punctuation in English; `;`, `&`, `()`, etc.

One advantage of Python is that it comes with a plethora of pre-written code you can use in the stdlib (including `requests` which you've used), one such library is [string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html), which contains the useful constant `punctuation`.

> string.punctuation
> String of ASCII characters which are considered punctuation characters in the C locale: `!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_\`{|}~.`

If we want to keep `'`, we can filter that our on your loop.
i.e.

```
for i in "?.!,":
    spelling_input = spelling_input.replace(i, "")
```

becomes

```
for i in (j for j in string.punctuation if j not in ("'", '"')):
    spelling_input = spelling_input.replace(i, "")
```

(N.B. this isn't the most efficient way to strip punctuation, but given it happens once, that's not too much of a concern)

### Simplifying logic

You are doing the same check against multiple cases when you download the websites. In order to avoid repeating ourselves (and not having a line that stretches into next week), we could replace:

```
    website1 = requests.get('https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/' + i)
    website2 = requests.get('https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/' + i.casefold())
    if (website1.status_code == 200 or website2.status_code == 200) and ("<span class=\"mw-headline\" id=\"English\">English</span>" in website1.text or "<span class=\"mw-headline\" id=\"English\">English</span>" in website2.text):
        print("\"" + i + "\"" + " is spelled right! :D")
    else:  # An `else .. if` should usually be an `elif`
        if (i[0] == '\'' or i[-1] == '\'') or (i[0] == '\"' or i[-1] == '\"'):
    [...]
```

with

```
    for case in (i, i.casefold()):
        website = requests.get('https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/' + case)
        if website.status_code == 200 and "<span class=\"mw-headline\" id=\"English\">English</span>" in website.text:  # Should probably make the string here a constant
            print("\"" + i + "\"" + " is spelled right! :D")
            break
    else:  # Python lets us do an `else` on a loop, which means `if exited naturally and not by break, etc.`
        if (i[0] == '\'' or i[-1] == '\'') or (i[0] == '\"' or i[-1] == '\"'):
            [...]
```

### Putting it all together

So when we add docstrings, main guard, split some things into functions we might end up with (untested as I don't have `autocorrect` installed)

**N.B.** Most of the comments here are for you to understand what I've changed and aren't good code documentation, make sure your code blocks are informatively, but not excessively, commented if they do more than a small thing.

```
"""
My spell checker using wiktionary
"""

import string
import requests
from autocorrect import Speller

WIKI_ADDRESS = 'https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/'
ENGLISH_HEADER = "<span class=\"mw-headline\" id=\"English\">English</span>"
SUCCESS_RESPONSE = 200
SPELL_CHECKER = Speller(lang='en')


def isquoted(inp: str) -> bool:
    """Checks if a string is quoted

    :param inp: String to be checked
    :returns: true if quoted, else false

    """
    return ((inp.startswith("'") and inp.endswith("'")) or
            (inp.startswith('"') and inp.endswith('"')))


def check_spelling(inp: str) -> tuple[str, list[str], list[str]]:
    """
    Checks the spelling of the input word-by-word

    :param inp: String to be checked
    :returns: Tuple of a corrected version, a list of misspellings and list of the new words
    """

    misspellings = set()
    spelling_input = inp
    spelling_output = inp

    for i in (j for j in string.punctuation if j not in ("'", '"')):
        spelling_input = spelling_input.replace(i, "")

    words = spelling_input.split()

    for word in words:
        for case in (word, word.casefold()):
            website = requests.get(WIKI_ADDRESS + case)
            if website.status_code == SUCCESS_RESPONSE and ENGLISH_HEADER in website.text:
                print(f'"{word}" is spelled right! :D')
                break
            # I honestly have very little idea what this next block was supposed
            # to be doing without comments
            # But I'm going to try to do what it says in your spec
        else:
            if isquoted(word):  # Ignore quoted words here
                continue
            print(f'"{word}" may be spelled wrong... :(')
            # Set takes care of duplicates
            misspellings.add(word)

    # Unindent this so it's done after we've got all the misspellings not each iteration
    for word in misspellings:
        if word[0].isupper():  # Skip Proper Nouns
            continue
        if word != SPELL_CHECKER(word):  # Spell checker found correction
            words = [SPELL_CHECKER(word) if x == word else x for x in words]
            spelling_output = spelling_output.replace(word, SPELL_CHECKER(word))
        else:
            # Here we inform the user their word was not fixed
            print(f'Your word "{word}" could not be fixed by spell checker')

    return spelling_output, misspellings, words


if __name__ == "__main__":  # Main guard allows us to import module functions and use them elsewhere
    # Loop until no input received from user
    while user_input := input("Input: "):
        corrected, misspellings, words = check_spelling(user_input)
        print(f"Corrected: {corrected}")
        print(f"Misspellings: {misspellings}")
        print(f"Words: {words}")
```

Comment: Quotation parameters tracks the indexes of each quotation mark in the input so that all characters in between a pair of items in the list (quotation marks) can be removed. Eg quotation_parameters = [a, b, c, d] all characters with index range(a, b) and range(c, d) are removed in spelling_output and excluded from for loop (pairing is covered by checking if qp index is even). This means that I can have quotations with multiple words eg. 'I have a dog' everything inside the quotes is removed unlike just the words 'I' and 'dog'. Nvm I see this in the function you did

Comment: I don't handle multiple words in a quote in this, but it's something you'd have to be careful with as obviously `"` and `'` are used in English for speech or emphasis. I would use something like `¬` to delimit (e.g `¬words words words¬`) as `¬` doesn't usually appear in English, the easiest way to extract these would something like `splt = sentence.split('¬'); words = splt[0::2]; quoted = splt[1::2]`, not necessarily the best, but simple and using inbuilts.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a useful review commenting on some code details. Here I'll
focus on a bigger question: how to build up maintainable programs using small
functions.

**Stop trying to do everything all at once**. Although your code has many
drawbacks due to its cramped layout, long lines, repetitions, and unhelpful
variable naming (all noted in another review), its biggest problem is
strategic: it tries to handle nearly everything at the same time. Within one
sprawling loop over `words`, you try to manage parsing details like where quotes
are located; send HTTP requests to two URLs; check for spelling corrections;
and reassemble the repaired text. That's a lot of complexity to manage in one
place. A better approach is to break the job down into much smaller tasks.

**Start from a solid foundation: functions**. The first step to building a
successful program is to commit to putting all of the logic inside of
functions. Here's the basic template for a script like this:

```
import sys

def main(args):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

**Make a high-level plan**. In this example, I will do most things as simply as
possible, leaving further details and exploration to you. Since I'd like to be
able to experiment, I want to be able to feed text into the program directly
from the command line. I also wanted to work with a moderately complex example,
so I borrowed the example from another review, editing it slightly. Here was my
initial sketch. Some parts were commented out, because I hadn't decided on the
precise form that the implementation would take.

```
import sys
import requests
from autocorrect import Speller

EXAMPLE = '''
    'Tis naïve for Guinea-Bissau to serve hors d'oeuvre at the France-Côte
    d'Ivoire all-american BBQ; the grocers' response was "unfavourable".
'''

def main(args):
    text = get_text_from_user(args)
    words = parse_text(text)
    # identify_proper_nouns(...)
    # check_wictionary(...)
    # get_correction(...)
    # display_results(...)
    print(words) # TEMP

def get_text_from_user(args):
    if args == ['--example']:
        return EXAMPLE
    elif args:
        return ' '.join(args)
    else:
        return input('Enter text: ').strip()

def parse_text(text):
    return text.split()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

**Use helpful data objects**. How should we represent a "word"? In your program
and in my initial sketch, a word is just a piece of text. But there are several
other pieces of information that need to travel with a word: is it a proper
noun, was it quoted, did we find it in Wictionary, is there a spelling
correction? In situations like this a dataclass is a good option. Each `Word`
instance will hold the text of the word plus any other details we will need.
For now, we can quickly adjust the parsing logic to use the new dataclass.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Word:
    text: str
    is_proper: bool = False
    was_quoted: bool = False
    in_wict: bool = False
    correction: str = None

def parse_text(text):
    return [
        Word(w)
        for w in text.split()
    ]
```

**Put sub-tasks in small, focused functions**. To fill in the other `Word`
attributes we need to perform various checks, each of which could be in its own
function. Here's how I started:

```
WICT_URL = 'https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/'

def main(args):
    spell_checker = Speller(lang='en')
    ...
    for w in words:
        w.is_proper = is_proper_noun(w)
        # w.was_quoted = ...
        w.in_wict = found_in_wictionary(w)
        w.correction = get_spelling_correction(spell_checker, w)
    ...

def is_proper_noun(w):
    return w.text[0].isupper()

def found_in_wictionary(w):
    url = WICT_URL + w.text
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        return response.status_code == 200
    except Exception:
        return False

def get_spelling_correction(checker, w):
    result = checker(w.text)
    return None if result == w.text else result
```

**Next steps: identifying words that were quoted**. I did not sketch this out
because text quoting is too complex for word-level analysis. To handle this
properly, you are going to need to enhance the text parsing process. My advice
is to break parsing into two phases: (1) divide the text into phrases, which
can be either quoted or unquoted (regular expressions and
a `Phrase` dataclass might be helpful here); then (2) break phrases apart into words,
setting their `was_quoted` attribute based on the type of phrase they came
from.

**Next steps: dealing with pesky punctuation**. Many types of punctuation marks
can be found in text. You are going to need to make some policy decisions
and/or select some third-party libraries to sort out your approach to this
issue.

**Next steps: performance**. Your current approach is doomed to be slow because
it makes an HTTP request per word. Such operations are orders of magnitude
slower than anything else your program is doing, so if you need speed, don't
bother fussing with anything else. One option is to abandon Wictionary: doesn't
the spellchecker already tell you whether the word is correctly spelled?
Another option is to obtain one of the [Wictionary data
dumps](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/), parse it into a small data file of valid
words, load that file once into memory, and then perform all checks against
that in-memory information.

**Next steps: stop abusing try-except**. Your code is littered with try-except structures.
That is a bad practice that will ultimately cause grief. Use try-except only when you are doing
something that is known to fail occasionally (for example, making an HTTP
request). Wrap the smallest portion of the code possible. If a try-except ends up wrapping a significant chunk of code,
because you can see no other way to handle the failure, that's a sure
sign that that the code needs a better strategy or should be decomposed further
into smaller steps.